# 500 Internal Server Error on ajax call with cakephp

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, cakephp

I developed a small website with cakephp working locally, and I moved in production environment on tophost. After have fighting with the .htaccess config file, I got the homepage to work. When I click on some buttons I should open the detail page, but I get 500 error on $.ajax call. Any ideas?

This is my .htaccess in the htdocs folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ /cakephp/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /cakephp/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the following is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/track",
   data: id,
   dataType: "text"
}).done(function(data) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use the original .htaccess file?

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error also in the homepage... :(